# Обновление файла через CURL и ошибки хттп сервера

Tags: linux, curl

Загружаю приложение таким образом

```
/usr/bin/curl -K /home/user/.config/curl-loader -o /home/user/.local/bin/app -z /home/user/.local/bin/app

#cat /home/kiosk/.config/curl-loader
URL=https://app.example.com/build/app
```

Но вот если сервер ответит 403 то в /home/user/.local/bin/app я получаю хтмлку от nginx.

Проблема в том что

```
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: никто не мешает потом взять и посмотреть. Вряд ли Вы ожидаете html файл и размер скорее всего ограничен. А можно и код [http посмотреть](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300021/how-i-get-the-http-responses-from-bash-script-with-curl-command)

Comment: Всё проще, ключ `-f`